# New Line Haskell

Tags: haskell, formatting

Hey. For a tutorial this week, one of the questions asks to create a function formatLines by using other functions formatLine and formatList, to format a list of lines.

My code looks like this;

```
type Line = String

formatLine :: Line -> String
formatLine l = l ++ "\n"

formatList :: (a -> String) -> [a] -> String
formatList f [] = []
formatList f xs = f (head xs) ++ formatList f (tail xs)

formatLines :: [Line] -> String
formatLines xs = formatList formatLine xs
```

The code seems (to me, at least) like it should work, but instead of creating a new line where "\n" is, \n gets appended to the string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is because you are probably using [`print`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Aprint) to print the result. Instead, use [`putStr`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3AputStr). Observe:

```
Prelude> print "test\ntest\n"
"test\ntest"
Prelude> putStr "test\ntest\n"
test
test
```

Other than that, you can use pattern matching to write `formatList` without [`head`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Ahead) and [`tail`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Atail):

```
formatList :: (a -> String) -> [a] -> String
formatList f [] = []
formatList f (x:xs) = f x ++ formatList f xs
```

But there is actually no need to define `formatList` yourself, as it is identical to the function [`concatMap`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3AconcatMap):

```
formatList :: (a -> String) -> [a] -> String
formatList = concatMap
```

Combining all this, you can also just write (note that `(++ "\n")` is a [*section*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator)):

```
formatLines :: [String] -> String
formatLines = concatMap (++ "\n")
```

...which in turn is equivalent to [`unlines`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Aunlines):

```
formatLines :: [String] -> String
formatLines = unlines
```

Comment: unlines, not unwords.  Using either is not really in the spirit of following a tutorial, but +1 for pointing out what's already available.

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
formatLines = unwords
```